# Scrape webpage that does not change URL

Tags: r, web-scraping

I’m new to web scraping. I can do the very basic stuff of scraping pages using URLs and css selector tools with R. Now I have run into problems.

For hobby purposes I would like to be able to scrape the following URL:  https://matchpadel.halbooking.dk/newlook/proc_baner.asp (a time slot booking system for sports)

However, the URL does not change when I navigate to different dates or adresses (‘Område’).

I have read a couple of similar problems suggesting to inspect the webpage, look under ’Network’ and then ‘XHR’ or ‘JS’ to find the data source of the table and get information from there. I am able to do this, but to be honest, I have no idea what to do from there.

I would like to retrieve data on what time slots are available across dates and adresses (the ‘Område’ drop down on the webpage).

If anyone is willing to help me and my understanding, it would be greatly appreciated.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The website you have linked looks to be run on Javascript which changes dynamically. You need to extract your desired information using `RSelenium` library which opens a browser and then you need to choose your dropdown and get data.

Find the sample code here to fire up firefox to your website. From here you can write codes to select different types of ‘Område’ dropdown and get the following table info using `remdr$getPageSource()` and then using `Rvest` functions to extract the data

```
# load libraries
library(RSelenium)

# open browser
selCommand <- wdman::selenium(jvmargs = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.verboseLogging=true"), retcommand = TRUE)
Sys.sleep(2)
shell(selCommand, wait = FALSE, minimized = TRUE)
Sys.sleep(2)
remdr <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L, browserName = "firefox")
Sys.sleep(10)
remdr$open()
remdr$navigate(url = 'https://matchpadel.halbooking.dk/newlook/proc_baner.asp')
```

Comment: So the only way is to simulate clicks to extract data one part at a time?  Sorry I can't read R, but is It what the code is doing? Is there a way to get the data in one go?